# How can I enable flick to scroll?

Tags: multi-touch, gestures

Is there a setting or a package to enable flick to scroll on Ubuntu?

I'd like to use this with my Apple Magic mouse and the two-finger scroll feature of my trackpad.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be possible. A quick google search showed that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently a driver for Apple's Magic Mouse is under development. If you're feeling adventurous, try [what they've got so far](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleMagicMouse). If you aren't comfortable with compiling the kernel, you might not want to mess with it. Otoh, compiling the kernel is pretty easy, so long as you're patient, willing to learn, and not on a super-important production system.

Comment: Compiling my own kernel sounds like a lot of work, considering that I have to do this for every update.

Comment: You could roll your own with Ubuntu's .config and the magic patch, then blissfully ignore kernel updates till the next LTS?